# Datastax DSE jar location

Tags: datastax-enterprise

I installed Datastax enterprise on my mac. 
Where can I find the dse.jar?

Or where can I download it from?

I want to use Spark and Cassandra helpers.

Thanks,
id

Answer (score 0):

To find dse.jar, run:

> sudo find / -name dse.jar

or within a particular directory:

> sudo find . -name dse.jar

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Package and Installer-Services installations 
then its locate in

```
/usr/share/dse
```

If you are using tarball installation then

```
installation_location/lib
```

**Note:**

In the old version of dse(like 4.6.1) this was called **dse.jar**, however the new version(e.g 5.1.7) it has been renamed to **dse-search-your-version.jar(e.g dse-search-5.1.7.jar)**